# ES6 Class compilation to ES5 function constructor

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, constructor, ecmascript-5, iife

I noticed something while playing with Typescript's compiler options. (Typescript is **irrelevant** here, I'm just using it as a compiler much like babel)

So, I have this code in .ts file

```js
(function () {
  class Person {
    name: string;

    constructor(n: string) {
      this.name = n;
    }
  }

  const jack = new Person("Jack");
  console.log(jack.name);
})();
```

When I run the compiler (I set the output to **es5**) , it gives me this:

```js
"use strict";
(function () {
    var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Person(n) {
            this.name = n;
        }
        return Person;
    }());
    var jack = new Person("Jack");
    console.log(jack.name);
})();
```

The Class is converted to constructor function, as expected.

But why does it need to be wrapped in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)? Wouldn't a simpler version, like the one below, suffice?

```js
"use strict";
(function () {
    
      function Person(n) {
          this.name = n;
      }
    var jack = new Person("Jack");
    console.log(jack.name);
})();
```

Comment: I would agree it comes down to the same in this case, but probably the transpiler chooses this pattern, foreseeing the support of private fields, which could result in other objects that are created in that closure (like a WeakMap, ...).

Comment: Try using the `class` as an expression, and add some private or static properties or static initialisers to it